# creating a shortcut on a remote desktop, but the shortcut is created with a "file" instead of "file folder" as the "target type"

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to create a shortcut on a remote desktop in the domain here, and I'm a domain admin. If I run the following code directly on the target machine, the shortcut can be created and is able to lead me to the target path.

```
$shortcutpath3 =  "c:\Users\Public\Desktop\Shortcuts to Test Custom\VV 1211 -TC.lnk"
$WshShell3 = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut3 = $WshShell3.CreateShortcut($shortcutpath3)
$Shortcut3.TargetPath = "\\machine\testcustom\"
$Shortcut3.Save()
```

I saved this script as test.ps1, run it with folloing code on a different mahchine. The code ends without any errors/warings, and the shortcut is created on the target machine with the propeties i specified. But it cannot lead me to the target place, it actually ask me to pick a program to open that file. I compared the properties of the 2 shortcuts, and found that the "target type" of the broken shortcut is "file" while it is "file folder" for a good shortcut.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TARGETSERVER -FilePath test.ps1
```

Any idea how i can fix this? And why is this happening? Thank!!!

Comment: Can you open the target path from the remote machine via windows explorer?

Comment: Yes, I can open the target path from the remote machine via windows explorer. And as I said, the shortcut works fine if I run the script directly on the target machine.

Comment: I cannot repro, and in my case the target type shows: Share (target server is 2008 R2). Does it helps if you remove the trailing backslash from the TargetPath?

Comment: Nope, removing the trailing backslash won't help. I had someone else try this and he gets the same result as yours.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and and I used Get-Item to make it work. Try this:

```
$targetPath = Get-Item("\\machine\testcustom\")
$WshShell3 = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut3 = $WshShell3.CreateShortcut($shortcutpath3)
$Shortcut3.TargetPath = $targetPath.FullName
$Shortcut3.Save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a domain admin I'd strongly recommend doing this with a [Group Policy Preference](http://4sysops.com/archives/group-policy-preferences-best-practices/). You can restrict shortcut creation to particular users/groups/computers/etc. via [item-level targeting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733022.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling this for the past several hours, Googling to no avail. For posterity, here's my summary. While alternatives suggestions are appreciated:

- PowerShell inexplicably has no direct way to create a shortcut. It can create symbolic link, but 1) it requires admin rights, and 2) it behaves differently.
- Group Policy Preferences are great--but only if your machines are in office or routinely on a VPN.
- If you're trying to create a shortcut to a network folder, setting the TargetPath to that folder only works if the computer actually can reach it when the script runs, i.e. same issue as with Group Policy Preferences. PowerShell *will* create the shortcut, but the Target Type will be a File rather than a File Folder (and I found no info online how to control that; trailing slash or not doesn't matter).
- The behavior of running these code suggestions varies depending whether you run this interactively or as a script.

Here's what I found *does* work:

- Set the $shortcut.TargetPath to "C:\Windows\Explorer.exe"
- Add a line: $shortcut.Arguments = """*Target folder*""" (the """ are needed as an escape character for the shortcut to show as C:\Windows\Explorer.exe "*Target folder*")

So for your example above, the following should work (assuming permissions to c:\Users\Public\Desktop):

```
$shortcutpath3 =  "c:\Users\Public\Desktop\Shortcuts to Test Custom\VV 1211 -TC.lnk"
$WshShell3 = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut3 = $WshShell3.CreateShortcut($shortcutpath3)
$Shortcut3.TargetPath = "C:\Windows\Explorer.exe"
$shortcut.Arguments = """\\machine\testcustom\"""
$Shortcut3.Save()
```